# Ignoring Highlighted Text Palette

Tags: c++, qt

In Qt 4.8, I have a `QTreeWidget`, and each node in the tree has its text colorized according to its value (e.g. green text for successful nodes, red for failures).

This is fine, but I'm running into issues when I try to select items in the tree. When an item is selected, Qt sets the selected text's `QPalette::ColorRole` to `QPalette::HighlightedText`. By default, this causes the text color to turn white. In a perfect world, I'd like the current selection to not change the text color at all.

From the documentation, it looks like `QPalette::setColor(ColorRole role, const QColor & color)` provides a means to change highlighted text's color, but it can only set the `ColorRole` to use a fixed color.

Is there a way to completely ignore the text color associated with a given `QPalette::ColorRole`? Ideally, I would like for the highlighted text color role to leave the text color alone; `QPalette::HighlightedText` wouldn't have a text color associated with it at all, and when text becomes highlighted it just keeps its non-highlighted color.

Is there any method to accomplish this easily in Qt? I'd like to avoid something like inheriting from `QPalette` or `QBrush` and hacking an overloaded function to do this, but I can't really find anything in the documentation that's helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

How're you doing to change the default unselected text color (`Qt::WindowText`, if I'm not mistaken) of each node? If you have a method with code like this:

```
palette.setColor(Qt::WindowText, color);
treeItem->setPalette(palette);
```

You could always just call `setColor()` for both color roles:

```
palette.setColor(Qt::WindowText, color);
palette.setColor(Qt::HighlightedText, color);
treeItem->setPalette(palette);
```

Hope this helps!